# Erasing area appears Black in android

Tags: android

i am developing an app in android where on moving finger erase functionality is used. 
in my app erasing feature is working properly but when we switch to next activity the erasing area appears black. please give any suggestion or link to remove this problem thanx in advance..
my code is

```
class EraseView extends View{
Bitmap bgr,bgr1;
Bitmap overlayDefault;
Bitmap overlay;
Paint pTouch;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
GlobalVariable globalVariable;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public EraseView(Context context,Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(context);
    globalVariable=(GlobalVariable)context.getApplicationContext();
    bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.erase_bg);
    bgr1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.erase_bg);
    overlayDefault =bitmap;
    overlayDefault = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(overlayDefault,globalVariable.bitmap_width, globalVariable.bitmap_height, true);
    overlay = bitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true); 
    overlay = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(overlay, globalVariable.bitmap_width, globalVariable.bitmap_height, true);
    c2 = new Canvas(overlay);
    pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
    pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
    pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
    globalVariable.bitmapArray=new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                X = (int) ev.getX();
                Y = (int) ev.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }           
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            globalVariable.count++;
            globalVariable.bitmapArray.add(globalVariable.bitmap);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    /*//draw background
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
    //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it                          
    c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, pTouch);
    //draw the overlay over the background  
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);*/
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Paint new_paint = new Paint(/*Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG*/);
    new_paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_ATOP));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, new_paint);
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 25, pTouch);
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, new_paint);
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(globalVariable.bitmap_width,globalVariable.bitmap_height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
   Canvas can=new Canvas(tempBitmap);
   can.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
   can.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);
    globalVariable.bitmap=tempBitmap;
}
}
```

Comment: I have got this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above question after erasing image erasing area appears black in next activity..
for this you replace this code by below code

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(globalVariable.bitmap_width,globalVariable.bitmap_height,       Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

in this if u set this code then definetly you find erasing area transparent..

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(globalVariable.bitmap_width,globalVariable.bitmap_height,       Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```